# Не сворачивается окно после разворачивания в fullscreen, в браузере GeckoFX

Tags: c#, winforms, gecko

Делаю мини браузер на основе GeckoFX 45. С помощью следующего кода:

```cs
Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/");
GeckoPreferences.User["full-screen-api.enabled"] = true;
GeckoPreferences.Default["full-screen-api.enabled"] = true;
```

открывается браузер с ютубом.

Если запустить видео и развернуть его на весь экран, то при попытке свернуть плеер к первоначальному размеру ничего не происходит. Плеер не реагирует на кнопку сворачивания.

Подскажите пожалуйста где я ошибся.

Comment: Привет. Ты у меня пропал с телеги.
Напиши мне https://t.me/GuitarFan03